# Unable to create a constant value - only primitive types or Enumeration types allowed

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have seen some questions related to this Exception here but none made me understand the root cause of the problem. So here we have one more...

```
var testquery = 
((from le in context.LoanEMIs.Include("LoanPmnt")
  join lp in context.LoanPmnts on le.Id equals lp.LoanEMIId
  where lp.PmntDtTm < date && lp.IsPaid == false
  && le.IsActive == true && lp.Amount > 0
  select new ObjGetAllPendingPmntDetails
  {
      Id = lp.Id,
      Table = "LoanEMI",
      loanEMIId = lp.LoanEMIId,
      Name = le.AcHead,
      Ref = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)le.FreqId),
      PmntDtTm = lp.PmntDtTm,
      Amount = lp.Amount,
      IsDiscard = lp.IsDiscarded,
      DiscardRemarks = lp.DiscardRemarks
  }).DefaultIfEmpty(ObjNull));

  List<ObjGetAllPendingPmntDetails> test = testquery.ToList();
```

This query gives the following Exception Message -

> Unable to create a constant value of type `CashVitae.ObjGetAllPendingPmntDetails`. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I got this Exception after I added the SQL function statement to convert `le.FreqId` which is a `byte` to a `string` as `ToString()` is not recognized in the LINQ Expression Store.

`ObjGetAllPendingPmntDetails` is a partial class in my model which is added as it is used too many times in the code to bind data to tables.
It has both `ID`s as long, 'Amount' as decimal, `PmntDtTm` as `Datetime`,`IsDiscard` as bool and remaining all are string including 'Ref'.

I get no results as currently no data satisfies the condition. While trying to handle null, I added `DefaultIfEmpty(ObjNull)` and `ObjNull` has all properties initialized as follows.

```
ObjGetAllPendingPmntDetails ObjNull = new ObjGetAllPendingPmntDetails()
{ Id = 0, Table = "-", loanEMIId = 0, Name = "-", Ref = "-",
  PmntDtTm = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-1900"),
  Amount = 0, IsDiscard = false, DiscardRemarks = "" };
```

I need this query to work fine as it has `Union()` called on it with 5 other queries. All returning the same `ObjGetAllPendingPmntDetails` columns. But there is some problem as this query has no data satisfying the conditions and the Exception Shared Above.

Any suggestions are appreciated as I am unable to understand the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Your `.DefaultIfEmpty(ObjNull)` code looks suspect to me. It doesn't look necessary, really, in that you're invoking `.ToList()` on the result. Do you really want the "no matching items found" case to try to return a `List` of length one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AndrewCoonce is right, the `.DefaultIfEmpty(ObjNull)` is the culprit here. Entity Framework turns `DefaultIfEmpty` into something like...

`CASE WHEN ([Project1].[C1] IS NULL) THEN @param ELSE [Project1].[Value] END AS [C1]`

...but there's no way to coerce an instance of `ObjGetAllPendingPmntDetails` into something that can take the place of `@param`, so you get an exception.

If you move the `DefaultIfEmpty` call to after the `ToList` it should work correctly (although you'll need to call `ToList` again after that if you really want a concrete list instance).