# Check if value is null, and when it is, execute extra (sub)query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is it possible to check for a null value in a LINQ query and when the value is null, that it executes an extra (sub)query, all at once?

**Explanation**

I have default buttons declared in my database, with default *descriptions*. A user can customize these buttons, and these settings are stored in the `ButtonLocations` table. Now, every button has a standard description and the user can edit this description. When the user edits the description, it is stored in the `Descriptions` table in my database. 
When I retrieve all buttons, I first check if a button has a specific description (in *buttonlocations*, with a left join). If this is not true (so null), I retrieve the default description.

Currently I get all my entities with their description and after that I loop through all of them to check if the value is null. This results in multiple queries to the database.

```
var temp = (from bl in context.buttonLocations
                    join b in context.Buttons
                    on bl.ButtonID equals b.ButtonID into buttons
                    from button in buttons.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join d in context.Descriptions
                    on new
                    {
                        ID = bl.ButtonLocationID,
                        langID = languageID,
                        originID = descriptionOriginID
                    }
                    equals new
                    {
                        ID = d.ValueID,
                        langID = d.LanguageID,
                        originID = d.DescriptionOriginID
                    }
                    into other
                    where bl.ButtonGroupID == buttonGroupId
                    from x in other.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        Button = button,
                        ButtonLocation = bl,
                        Description = x
                    }).ToList();

        // Retrieve default descriptions if no specific one is set
        foreach (var item in temp)
        {
            if (item.Description == null)
            {
                item.Description = context.Descriptions
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValueID == item.Button.ButtonID && x.LanguageID == languageID && x.DescriptionOriginID == (short)DescriptionOriginEnum.Button);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Colin's answer using the coalesce operator ought to work, but if it can't be made to you could try doing a subselect which gets both options, then ordering by preference for custom source, and taking the top record. (I'm assuming here that any given button only really has one description, and multiple descriptions shouldn't result in multiple buttons.)

```
var temp = (from bl in context.buttonLocations
        join b in context.Buttons
        on bl.ButtonID equals b.ButtonID into buttons
        from button in buttons.DefaultIfEmpty()
        let description = (
                from d in context.Descriptions
                where
                    d.LanguageID == languageID
                 && (
                      (
                        d.ValueID == bl.ButtonLocationID
                        && d.DescriptionOriginID == descriptionOriginID
                      )
                    ||
                      (
                        d.ValueID == b.ButtonID 
                        d.DescriptionOriginID == (short)DescriptionOriginEnum.Button
                      )
                    )
                // this line puts custom descriptions first
                orderby d.DescriptionOriginID == (short)DescriptionOriginEnum.Button
                        ? 1
                        : 0
                select d
                )
                // this will get a custom description if there was one, otherwise
                // the first one will be the default description
                .FirstOrDefault() 
        where bl.ButtonGroupID == buttonGroupId
        select new
        {
          Button = button,
          ButtonLocation = bl,
          Description = description
        })
        .ToList();
```

This is obviously a bit awkward, and probably not the most efficient query. I would try moving the coalesce operator to a `let description = d ?? /*subselect*/` line first.

Answer (score 0):

The [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) should work for you here. Something like this:

```
.....
select new
{
   Button = button,
   ButtonLocation = bl,
   Description ?? context.Descriptions
                         .FirstOrDefault(
                         x => x.ValueID == button.ButtonID 
                         && x.LanguageID == languageID 
                         && x.DescriptionOriginID == (short)DescriptionOriginEnum.Button)
})
```

Comment: I tried this already, it did not work. It gives following error: *'Unable to create a null constant value of type 'Description'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.'*

Comment: I think your error is coming from entity framework because it cannot translate your code into sql. `(short)DescriptionOriginEnum.Button` might be the culprit - try assigning it to a `short` variable before you construct your query. And this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17847159/150342

Comment: Both proposed solutions don't help. I guess it is not possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, just that I don't think in linq well enough to help much. I think this is worth a read http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/ and introducing variables as @SteveRuble has shown helps too